# How to join two txt files, record by record, with fuzzy key? (approximate matching)

Tags: regex, join, text

I have multiple text files, containing records with multiple fields delimited by *tabs*, all files have a "key" that is fuzzy (as a name can be, with spelling issues and typos).

**File 1**:  Format: `Title \t field1 \t ... fieldn \n` 

    `Title               Original title  Year
    21                  21              2008
    21 Jump Street      21 Jump Street  2012
    22 Jump Street      22 Jump Street  2014
    27 volte in bianco  27 Dresses      2008
    Clerks - Commessi   Clerks          2006
...`

**File 2:** Format: `Title \t field1 \t ... fieldn \n` 
    `Title               Director
    21                  Rob
    21 Jump Street      Lord&Miller
    22 Jump Street      Lord,Miller
    27 volte in bianco  Fletcher
    Clerks: Commessi    Smith
...`

**File 3:** Format: `Title \t field1 \t ... fieldn \n` 
    `Title              Filename
    21                 "21.mkv"
    21 Jump Street     "21 Jump St.avi"
    27 volte in bianco "27 Dresses.avi"
    Clerks - Commessi  "Clerks.avi"`

**File n:**  Format: `Title \t field1 \t ... fieldn \n` 
    `Title              Descripted in
    21                 "21.mht"
    21 Jump Street     "21JS.mht"
    22 Jump Street     "22.mht"
    27 volte in bianco "27dres.mht"
    Clerks - Commessi  "Clerks.mht"`

I would to create an output that orderly join all records (including incomplete and unmatched) of all files, using Title as key, but allowing a little differences between keys (see how clerks use **:** instead of **-** in file 2), ideally giving a warning when matching is not exact (char by char):

**Output**: Format `field1 \t field2 \t ... fieldn \n
Warning Title   Original title      Year    Director    Filename        Description
No  21              21              2008    Rob         "21.mkv"        "21.mht"
No  21 Jump Street  21 Jump Street  2012    Lord&Miller "21 JS.avi"     "21JS.mht"
No  22 Jump Street  22 Jump Street  2014    Lord,Miller                 "22.mht"
No  27 volte in bianco  27 Dresses  2008    Fletcher    "27 Dress.avi"  "27dress.mht"
Yes Clerks - Commessi   Clerks      2006    Smith       "clerks.avi"    "Clerks.mht"`

How a fuzzy match can be done and marked by warning=Yes? (as with similar but not equal key for Clerks in file 2) and how to manage missing records (note that 3rd record (22 Jump street) do not have a record in file 3, thus all missing fields must be substituted by tabs only (\t) in the output file to mantain correct column order in all records).
The most difficult parts are these two, at least for me.

Any suggestion? Any tool suggested for the job ?

Comment: What code have you tried? Questions seeking tool recommendations are off topic for StackOverflow per the [Help Center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I usually did similar things using PowerGrep (regular expressions) but I'm open to any solution, i'm willing to install a new tool or language to do the job.

Comment: I'm open to any solution, I'm willing to install a new tool or language to do the job, that was the meaning of the question about the tool: trying to leave options open to any useful answer. I'm not trying to start opinionated discussions about what is better, though. :-)

Comment: Googling around I discovered this is a problem already known, enough to merit a name (approximate string matching: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) and that some tools have been already developed (http://search.cpan.org/~bkb/Text-Fuzzy-0.17/lib/Text/Fuzzy.pod My perl knowledge is almost zero, but could be a good reason to start learning it). I'm prepared to code a solution, if needed, but seems difficult to accept no one else already had the same problem and find a better solution than a newbie...

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Questions with code also tend to be more objectively answerable. As it stands, your question isn't really a good fit for the site.

Comment: If I bothered you in any way, please be aware english is not my first language, and my proficiency is not enough to undestand if I'm writing politely as I would. I'm not looking for someone to do the job instead of me, just looking for advice. Thought this kind of problem may be a common problem that someone else already encountered and willing to share his solution. Sorry.

Comment: Your remarks are perfectly polite and your English is wonderful. These do not improve the question. Only code will improve it.

Comment: You're surely right, but before coding I believe choosing the right language/tool is the most important part to save time and effort. I know there are many languages/tools, in which I have no experience, designed to manage efficiently strings, text files, comma delimited files and so on (example: perl, awk, grep) and googling around I discovered others designed to manage comparison between strings with typos (example: TRE, FREJ, agrep) and before making a choice (test all of them? Choose one and test that? Which one first?)  I was looking help
Maybe I will code something with agrep to start..